# Using Legend in a User-Defined Function in R

Tags: r

First off, my knowledge of R is in it's infant stages, so forgive me if I come across ignorant.

I am writing a user defined function that will place the R^2 and p-value on a scatterplot with a linear regression. Here is the code so far:

```
stats.insert <- function(data, x, y)
{
reg1<-with(data,lm(y~x))
fit<-abline(reg1, col="blue")
modsum = summary(reg1)
r2=modsum["r.squared"]
my.p <- coef(modsum)[2,4]
rp=vector('expression',2)
rp[1]=substitute(expression(italic(R)^2==MYVALUE),
   list(MYVALUE=format(r2,dig=3)))[2]
rp[2]=substitute(expression(italic(p)== MYOTHERVALUE),
  list(MYOTHERVALUE=format(my.p,digits=2)))[2]       
legend("bottomleft",legend=rp,bty='n')
}
```

This is great, however, I would also like to specify the the location of the legend. So the function would look like this:

```
stats.insert <- function(data, x, y, placement)
```

where placement would be within the legend function. The problem I'm having is that I cant get around the "" within the legend function.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to R and SO.

There are many ways to create a function that would work well for your purposes.

```
# Function stats.insert
# Args: 
#   formula : see ?lm
#   data:  a data.frame, see ?lm
#   ...    Arguments passed to the legend() for the plot
#
# Return:
#   A plot of the data with the regression line, and the coefficient of
#   determination, and a p-value in a legend.

stats.insert <- function(formula, .data, ...) {
  reg1 <- lm(formula, data = .data)

  modsum <- summary(reg1)
  r2     <- format(modsum["r.squared"], digits = 3)
  my.p   <- format(coef(modsum)[2,4], digits = 2)

  rp     <- vector('expression', 2)
  rp[1]  <- substitute(expression(italic(R)^2==MYVALUE),list(MYVALUE=format(r2,dig=3)))[2]
  rp[2]  <- substitute(expression(italic(p)== MYOTHERVALUE), list(MYOTHERVALUE=format(my.p,digits=2)))[2]       

  abline(reg1, col="blue")
  legend(..., legend = rp, bty = 'n')
}

with(mtcars, plot(wt, mpg))
stats.insert(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, "bottomright")
stats.insert(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, "topright")
stats.insert(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, x = 2, y = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm enjoying the learning process! Thanks also for your help on this. Your approach is much more fluid than mine.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
stats.insert <- function(data, x, y,placement="bottomleft")
{

    lots of code ...

    legend(placement,legend=rp,bty='n')
}
```